# Passing `null` parameter from jscript to COM interface?

Tags: com, null, jscript

Consider the following interface definitions:

```
[
    //...
    dual,
    //...
]
interface IFoo : IDispatch{
}

[
    //...
    dual,
    //...
]
interface IBar : IDispatch{
  [propput, id(1)] HRESULT foo([in] IFoo* newVal);
};
```

I'm working with an object implementing `IBar` in JScript:

`myBar.foo = someFoo;` // so far so good

How can I set `foo` to `null`?

`myBar.foo = null;` // "Type mismatch"

`myBar.foo = 0;` // "Type mismatch"

Comment: I'm unsure, but shouldn't `IFoo*` be `optional` here?

Comment: @Anton Kovalenko optional `propput` argument? There's no such thing in IDL. And if it were exist, how would you use it? `myBar.foo = ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: it's impossible.